# One big GridFS collection in MongoDB or many smaller?

Tags: mongodb, blob, large-files, gridfs

We're using MongoDB for storing video data before and after conversion. Encoding of one file results of six or more smaller files (several quality grades and different formats). Both input and output files shares the same unique file id.

The question is which approach is better in terms of performance and scalability: to store all output files in one huge gridFS collection with compound keys containing original file id, quality grade and format type or to have separate collection for each quality / format pair?

For me both these approaches have their own pros and cons, i.e.

- Using one big resulting collection uses less configuration during read time, but more complex query will be needed to find the file;
- Using several resulting collections involves simpler and quicker queries, but requires additional configuration to select to which collection this query should be addressed.

It looks for me more like matter of personal choice... But what about scalability or performance? Have anyone faced with solution like this before? Maybe someone could advise?

Which approach is better from strategic point of view, taking into account large number of files of large size? Which approach will be easier to scale and shard in the future? Maybe there are performance penalties in long run?

Comment: I think it's going to be a question of manageability and performance. I wouldn't have thought to store video data in MongoDB. Did you consider alternatives like HDFS?

Comment: I haven't tried HDFS, so my impression is not full, but for me they both (GridFS and HDFS) do the same job, and I haven't heard that one of them is significantly better than other... If you do have such documents, please share with me, maybe you're right and I need to reconsider storage layer.

Comment: I suppose it depends a lot on the volume and size of files you're talking about. I think of HDFS easily scaling into the petabyte range.